# What do these small buttons next to a unit's stats do?

Tags: civilization-6

When a unit is selected, its stats are shown in the lower right part of the screen:

[image: Unit stats]

Recently I noticed that the small icons next to the combat strength and the movement points can be clicked and behave like toggle buttons:

[image: Combat strength clicked]
[image: Combat strength and movement points clicked]

However there is no tooltip and I didn't notice any action triggered by these buttons.

Do they have any function? If so, what do they do?

Comment: It could just be a bug with their UI where it's recognized as a button.  I've noticed you can click on things on the menus which don't have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the Spring 2017 update, and perhaps some time before that, this is no longer an issue: the buttons have been changed to icons, clicking on them no longer changes their appearance, and the tooltip text for the question mark is the same as for the image of the unit itself on the left (unit name and hit points).

[image: image of Civ VI musketman with updated icons]

There is no tooltip for the movement icon; if you leave your pointer over it, you'll eventually get the tooltip for the underlying hex.

Answer (score 0):

It is purely a cosmetic thing and these buttons perform no actions. They are just recognized as a button and given an alternative color as would most other buttons. It's not something to worry about and it's not something they are likely to address.